# Setting border-radius for QSpinBox/QComboBox has unexpected side effect on up/down controls

Tags: css, qt4, pyqt4, qcombobox, qspinbox

I'm using PyQt4 to make an interface with a number of QLineEdit and QSpinBox inputs. I want to give both a nice rounded appearance, but this gives a problem in the case of the spinboxes.

The relevant bits of the stylesheet looks like this:

```
QDialog {
    background-color: #444;
}

QLabel, QLineEdit, {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

QSpinBox{
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Giving an interface looking like this:

[image: UI screenshot]

Now when I include a `border-radius` (even with a value of 0) for QSpinBox and QComboBox, I get this

[image: Glitchy UI screenshot]

Notice how the arrows changed from Windows XP/vista themed to a plain default look.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

What I would like to see is that the main shapes of the spinbox and combobox are shaped like the line edits. I have not tried setting custom arrow images, as I would prefer to use the native defaults. Or is that really my best/only option? Thanks!

Comment: JNK is going to be VERY angry with you

Comment: this guy http://stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk

Comment: Ah, right :D Well I guess Arthur C. Clarke would have more reason to be angry with the both of us.

Comment: you better change it quick before he finds out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through this [QStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle.html), where you get the idea to change the style of your widget to [QWindowsStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwindowsstyle.html), [QMacStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmacstyle.html) or [QMotifStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmotifstyle.html). And also if you set stylesheet of a particular widget, only the values `set` by you will be updated, rest other properties are `inherited` from its `parent` widget. so try specifying `widget style` too as I said above while setting `stylesheet`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links. For now I decided to make my own images anyway, but this might help in the future.

Answer (score 2):

When you change style sheet of widget it becomes styled with QCssStyle. It fall backs every not styled subcontrol into default style. You must style whole control to get desired look. It won't mix

Comment: Thanks. But why didn't background-color revert the buttons back to default then?

Comment: Because background color doesn't change shape